# Android Google Analytics config generation not working

Tags: android, configuration, google-analytics

When I attempt to generate a configuration in the tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

When I select "Get a Configuration File" A site launches and then a spinner starts spinning and continues spinning with no json config file loading.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it doesn't load the page completely. However I didn't use that link to get configuration file. You just need Tracking ID to create an analytics configuration file.
Use this tutorial to implement Google analytic for your project.

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/

Comment: Thank you. I was also missing some of the setup steps.